# Is a read with one secondary index faster than a read with multiple in cassandra?

Tags: cassandra, cql, database, nosql

I have this structure that I want a user to see the other user's feeds.
One way of doing it is to fan out an action to all interested parties's feed.

That would result in a query like select from feeds where userid=

otherwise i could avoid writing so much data and since i am already doing a read I could do:

select from feeds where userid IN (list of friends).

is the second one slower? I don't have the application yet to test this with a lot of data/clustering. As the application is big writing code to test a single node is not worth it so I ask for your knowledge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your title is correct, and `userid` is a secondary index, then running a `SELECT/WHERE/IN` is not even possible.  The `WHERE/IN` clause only works with primary key values.  When you use it on a column with a secondary index, you will see something like this:

```
Bad Request: IN predicates on non-primary-key columns (columnName) is not yet supported
```

Also, the DataStax CQL3 [documentation for SELECT](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cql/3.0/cql/cql_reference/select_r.html) has a section worth reading about using `IN`:

> **When not to use IN**
>
> The recommendations about when not to use an index apply to using IN
>   in the WHERE clause. Under most conditions, using IN in the WHERE
>   clause is not recommended. Using IN can degrade performance because
>   usually many nodes must be queried. For example, in a single, local
>   data center cluster with 30 nodes, a replication factor of 3, and a
>   consistency level of LOCAL_QUORUM, a single key query goes out to two
>   nodes, but if the query uses the IN condition, the number of nodes
>   being queried are most likely even higher, up to 20 nodes depending on
>   where the keys fall in the token range.

As for your first query, it's hard to speculate about performance without knowing about the cardinality of `userid` in the feeds table.  If `userid` is unique or has a very high number of possible values, then that query will not perform well.  On the other hand, if each `userid` can have several "feeds," then it might do ok.

Remember, Cassandra data modeling is about building your data structures for the expected queries.  Sometimes, if you have 3 different queries for the same data, the best plan may be to store that same, redundant data in 3 different tables.  And that's ok to do.

I would tackle this problem by writing a table geared toward that specific query.  Based on what you have mentioned, I would build it like this:

```
CREATE TABLE feedsByUserId
    userid UUID,
    feedid UUID,
    action text,
    PRIMARY KEY (userid, feedid));
```

With a composite primary key made up of `userid` as the [partitioning key](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cql/3.1/share/glossary/gloss_partition_key.html) you will then be able to run your `SELECT/WHERE/IN` query mentioned above, and achieve the expected results.  Of course, I am assuming that the addition of `feedid` will make the entire key unique.  if that is not the case, then you may need to add an additional field to the `PRIMARY KEY`.  My example is also assuming that `userid` and `feedid` are version-4 UUIDs.  If that is not the case, adjust their types accordingly.

Comment: I want my column family to be like: feedid,action,userid and select all actions for a given userid which i expect/hope to be a large value.
sorry about the secondary key IN clause, I am just starting out with CQL and cassandra.

Comment: @arisalexis No worries.  I made an edit to provide an example query table.  Hope this helps!